# Upgrading concern named Filter in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby, separation-of-concerns, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have the following structure:

```
- app
  - models
    ...
    user.rb
    - concerns
      ...   
      - user 
        ...
        filters.rb
```

And the following two classes

```
#app/models/user.rb:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  ...
  include User::Filters
  ...
end

#app/models/concerns/user/filters.rb:
module User::Filters 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods 
    def filter_on_xxx
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

However, I now run: `User.filter_on_xxx`
but i Get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `filter_on_xxx' for User
```

This worked fine in rails 4.0.x

Not sure how to work around this without removing the concern and just moving it into the main class and using `concerning` which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the upgrade to rails 4.1 meant that the name Filters was no longer allowed. Rename the file and the module to Filtering

i.e.

```
#app/models/concerns/filtering.rb
module User:Filtering
...
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include User::Filtering
  ...
end
```